# Measure screen load time in Flutter in library

Tags: flutter, performance

I am developing a library and want to be able to measure screen load times of my users.

For example:

- user pushes a screen -> screen load timer starts
- screen has rendered frame -> screen load timer stops

I have tried using a `NavigationObserver` and `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` but I am not sure if this leads to correct results.

```dart
@override
void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
  // start timer

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    // end timer
  });
}
```